# What happened here at the proof of associative law for addition?

Tags: induction, proof-explanation, associativity

I was glancing through appendix of M Artin algebra in the integers section and here is a proof by using mathematical induction on the basis of Peano's axiom.

Proof for associative law for addition:
Definition referred in the proof is given below (keep in mind that $'$ represents succession by one, e.g., $1'= 2$, $3'= 4$)

Addition: $m + 1 = m'$ and $m + n'=(m+n)'$

Multiplication: $m \cdot 1 = m$ and $m \cdot n' = m \cdot n + m$

Now here is the proof:

We are to prove that $(a + b) + n = a + (b + n)$ for all $a, b, n$ belonging to $\mathbb{N}$. We first check the case $n = 1$ for all $a, b$. Three
applications of definition (given above) give
$$(a + b) + 1 = (a + b)' = a + b' = a + (b + 1)$$
Next, assume the associative law true for a particular value of $n$ and for all $a, b$.
Then we verify it for $n'$ as follows:

$(a + b) + n' = (a + b) + (n + 1)$ (definition)

$= ((a + b) + n) + 1$        (case $n = 1$)

$= (a + (b + n)) + 1$ (induction hypothesis)

$= a + ((b + n) + 1)$ (case $n = 1$)

$= a + (b + (n + 1))$ (case $n = 1$)

$= a + (b + n')$ (definition). proved

Now my question is exactly what happened at step $2$, how did it transition from step i.e., $(a+b)+n' = (a+b) + (n+1)$ to $((a+b)+n)+1$, rest all is fine but reference for step $2$ doesn't fit in. Please explain

Although it's bit silly but I'm getting terribly confused.

Reference: M Artin Appendix A2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happened with:

> $(a + b) + n' = (a + b) + (n + 1)$ (definition)
>
> $= ((a + b) + n) + 1$ (case $n = 1$) ?

We consider $(a+b)$ as a single number; call it $A$.

We have:

> $A+(n+1)= (A+n)+1$

and it holds by the base case ($k=1$) already proved.

Comment: Oh I should've thought that beforehand. Alright, do you have any reference or book where I can get mre proofs like these for natural numbers. ( Associative, commutative, distribution and others)

Comment: @Manny46 - many... Terence Tao, [Analysis I](https://books.google.it/books?id=ecTsDAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), Springer (3rd ed, 2016) and Ethan Bloch, [The real numbers and real analysis](https://books.google.it/books?id=r0qcU9U2_I4C&printsec=frontcover), Springer (2011) and Ethan Bloch, [Proofs and Fundamentals: A First Course in Abstract Mathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=QJ_537n8zKYC&printsec=frontcover), Springer (2nd ed, 2011).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. So basically what I was looking for was there in analysis textbooks. I'm in first year of college and we have some parts of matrix algebra, theory of equations, relations and mapping, group, ring field. I am bit confused with the sequence to go by, since it seems bit out of what I've studied so far. So, I decided to start from the beginning so natural numbers and it's properties and some proofs. Can you tell me what should be the correct order for maths after calculus so as to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Manny46 - you can see Bloch's Proofs for an intro to "fundamentals": sets, relations, functions. up to natural numbers. Then two threads: from numbers to reals and calculus, and from functions and relations to abstract algebra (groups, rings, etc.) and vectors and matrix.